# Make a USB stick act like a CD

Tags: usb-flash-drive, autorun

I used to have a [U3 memory stick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U3) that came with two partitions, the [FAT32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT32) one with data and one that acted like a CD drive so that the executable in it ran automatically under Windows. How can I make my memory stick have two partitions like this forcibly so that I can have a read-only part of my memory stick that also runs the auto-run automatically in Windows?

I'm perfectly confident with using tools like [GParted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GParted), and the like too.

Comment: Is the read-only a requirement, or would one partition with some autorunning apps be sufficient?  (I guess you could mark them read-only files but that doesn't stop deletions obviously)

Comment: Just running apps would be good. Read-only is not necessary, thanks.

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.squidoo.com/usbcd

Comment: @Sandeep - That looks like a potentially useful tool, if you have a drive it actually supports.  Why didn't you make that an answer?

Comment: Yes, it does look very interesting!

Comment: @Shinrai I wouldn't have really thought it was a full answer to the question as it just explains various aspects of it

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Portable Apps](http://portableapps.com/) to great success before.  Basically it lets you install portable versions of applications (and they have compatibility fixes for TONS of them) and run them directly from their launcher utility.

The installer for the utility should set it up as an autorun, unless they've changed this since the last time I used it.  In the event that it doesn't, this is easy enough to set up, but note that it varies from OS to OS.  In particular, old fashioned autorun.inf won't work under Windows 7 anymore.  [There's a good bit of detail on this here](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/autorun-usb-flash-drive.htm) and [also here](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/autorun-usb-flash-drive-windows-7.htm).  To get autorun working under Windows 7 requires special firmware on the drive and/or some specialty software preinstalled on the machine.

Comment: The problem is that I want the autorun to start automatically. In Windows, the autorun is not started the moment the USB stick is put in because of security reasons. U3 got around this by making a CD partition on their USB sticks, and that is what I'm wanting to do on a generic USB stick.

Comment: @TomMan - See the edits I was in the process of writing.  You never specified Windows 7 - that's a very different animal, unfortunately.  (And I believe the U3 functionality is not just simple partitioning, unfortunately, but some firmware trickery as well to report the partition type differently.)

Comment: Sorry about that. Thanks for the links, I shall look into those.

Answer (score 1):

*Some* flash controllers used on USB sticks have built-in functionality to emulate CD/DVD drives (on a given partition on the stick). Generally this can't be turned on by the user without access to the proprietary tools of the chip, which aren't distributed to the general public, but given to stick makers (who often are not the same companies as the controller makers).

There's a Russian site that provides (probably illegal in the West due to copyright issues) access to some to these tools and discussion threads on using them ([random example](https://flashboot.ru/forum/index.php?topic=11040.0): discussing the Innostor IS9xx family.). There's also another Russian site with more how-to’s for other chip families, e.g. some [Phison](https://www.usbdev.ru/articles/a_phison/pscdrom/) or [aa](https://www.usbdev.ru/articles/a_smi/cdrom_sm3252c/). It's a bit of an adventure to do this, even if you happen to (1) identify the chip and (2) find the tool for it — the tool's interface is sometimes only available in Chinese, depending on the chip maker. (Typically these are based on the "MPTools" framework, but it needs to be configured for your device — like know the type of memory chips too, otherwise it will not work or brick it.)

(I happen to have one such a [Huawei-branded] device, but it's a more complex one than simple flash stick: it's a 4G (USB) modem with an additional flash storage that's half used for a CD emulation to install drivers for the modem and some "courtesy" area that's useable as a flash drive by the user for their own files. Additionally, this device has a micro-SD card reader built-in too, next to the SIM slot.)

I should add here that flash partitions (of this firmware-based kind) are not the same thing as drive[r] level partitions handled by the OS. You can only create the former with tool specific to the USB flash chip. They also show as different USB devices on the same "hub"; more correctly said — a USB composite device (which is multi-function but doesn't emulate a hub — the latter [would be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_device) a compound device in USB tech jargon).

Anyhow, if you wonder why reconfiguration like that isn't more common (besides the CD emulation), it's because you'd have unplug and replug the device [even if just at the USB logical level] for the new chip-based partition scheme to register — there's [no support](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/arm-based-microcontrollers-group/arm-based-microcontrollers/f/arm-based-microcontrollers-forum/1030026/tm4c123fh6pm-usb-dinamically-add-and-remove-cdc-devices-to-composite-usb-device?tisearch=e2e-sitesearch&keymatch=TM4C123FH6PM) in USB for a composite device to change its topology without a disconnect/reconnect cycle — it's only done at enumeration time.

Comment: Great answer! Nice work.