# load USB drive as CD drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb-flash-drive, compact-disc, autorun

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make a USB Stick act like a CD](https://superuser.com/questions/282155/make-a-usb-stick-act-like-a-cd)

After reading the comments below, it seems that Windows 7 only supports the label and icon entries. I followed the link they commented and read that only CD's are allowed to use the autorin.inf entries.

Are there any ways on how to load the usb as a cd drive? I researched and only saw people loading a usb as a hard drive with the use of a custom inf file.

Answer (score 0):

There are several freeware/shareware options that create a virtual CD drive under windows from a ISO file.
So if you can dump the contents of your USB drive to a ISO file, that route should work for you.
The ISO file is an image file of the entire CD. If you are familiar with the UNIX dd command, the several utilities that are available, pretty much wrap that functionality for you.

Comment: The flash drive itself is empty. I just want it to appear as a CD drive from Windows' point of view

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, Windows 7 does not support more than setting the label/image via the autorun.inf file for USB devices. Because the device itself advertises as being writable, as a result Windows takes the 'Removable USB device' code path.

If you get a [U3 device](http://u3.sandisk.com/), it can make a separate partition appear as a CDROM device. There are software tools to customize the content of this.

If you want to make windows insecure then you can [futz around with the AutoRun/AutoPlay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoRun) settings.

Comment: So it means if the device is writable, it cannot be a CDROM device? I was looking for a tweaked driver file that can make your USB a show up like a cdrom. All I found is for making your USB appear as a hard drive

Comment: pretty much. There's no practical way to make the device appear as a CDROM device

Comment: If you're trying to get windows to autorun things for you, then futzing around with the AutoRun/AutoPlay settings might be an option for you