# How to make USB stick to appear CD ROM

Tags: usb-flash-drive, autorun

How I can make my memory stick have two partitions like this force-ably so that i can have a read-only part of my memory stick that also runs the auto-run automatically in Windows?

There is a same question in 
[Make a USB stick act like a CD](https://superuser.com/questions/282155/make-a-usb-stick-act-like-a-cd)

But the solution link is no more working

Comment: The solution by uSlackr still works.  I should point out Windows does not support USB flashes devices to be partitioned in this maner.  The U3 devices talked about in the linked question were discontinued because they were a BAD idea.

Comment: I have the exact requirement of "Tom lease"( make a normal memmory stick appear as CD-ROM ) and he made it by this link( http://www.squidoo.com/usbcd) ,so I'm seeking the information inside this link

Comment: The link is dead. We cannot tell you what was contained on that website.  But a combination of making a small partition, autorun ( which is disabled in recent version of Windows ), and making the smaller partition read-only could emulate what you need.  The disk icon just wouldn't be a "cd-rom" icon.

Comment: For those wanting to see the link, [it is still live via the wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20120827031725/http://www.squidoo.com/Usbcd)

Answer (score 1):

Something like ultraiso could work, the problem is the CD partition could be removed if you Erase the drive through something like diskpart in Windows.  To get a true CD partition, it needs to be setup on the USB controller itself, on the device, at the hardware level.

Done this way, it is a true CD-ROM partition and connot be changed or removed.  I used some gear from [nexcopy](https://www.nexcopy.com/usb-duplicator/) and their duplicator/software allowed for this.  It also gave us the option to use the remaining memory space as a read/write drive.  I think that is what you are after.

Duplicator will cost you some cash, so not sure if this is applicable to and end-user, but it's what you are after.

Actually, Windows doesn't support auto-run for USB sticks anylonger anyway, so might be a mute point these days.