# How to Protect files on USBs

Tags: usb, format, read-only

So I want to have files on my USB Stick, which you cannot delete or edit, so read only. They also need to remain on the USB when formatted by Windows, or diskmgmt.msc. Is there any way of making certain files read only, so they cannot be formatted, deleted or edited?

The USB doesn't have a switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first possibility is, to make the usb read only. But the files still be deleted when the USB-device get formatted:

> 1. Log on with your Windows administrator account. You will only be able to make a storage device or any file read-only if you have
>      administrative privileges.
> 2. Connect the USB drive into the USB port on the side or back of your laptop or desktop computer.
> 3. Click "Start" and double-click on the "Computer" icon.
> 4. Right-click on the USB drive and select the "Properties" option from the drop-down menu.
> 5. Click on the "Security" tab and select the "Edit" option. Find the section "Write Attributes" and place a check mark next to the
>      "Read-Only" option.
> 6. Click on the "Apply" or "OK" button in the bottom right corner of the "Properties" window to save all your changes and make the USB
>      drive have read-only attributes.
>
> [Source](http://www.ehow.com/how_8645521_make-usb-readonly.html#ixzz2gCuRdMBP)

The second possibility is, to create a hidden partition, which stays, even after the device was formatted: [How to create a hidden Partition with FbInst](http://www.instructables.com/id/Create-a-Hidden-Partition-on-USB-Flash-Drive-which/)

Answer (score 0):

Not in the classical case, no.   As a USB disk is not write-once media, a format or disk wipe will always be able to erase the data.  Similarly if you repartition a disk you will be able to get rebuild the partition table and erase the old one.

As you say, the USB doesn't have a switch.   You could (probably) get round this by getting an SD to USB convertor and locking the SD card, which would prevent overwriting of anything on the disk - short of flipping the switch.

A partial software solution to your problem has been expounded [here](https://superuser.com/questions/282155/make-a-usb-stick-act-like-a-cd).

Comment: Two notes on the SDcard WP switch: 1) They only seem to be on the normal sised once (e.g. no switch on miniSD or microSD). 2) They do not hardware write protect the card. They just set a flag 'please consider me write protected'.

Answer (score -1):

What you asked for is literally impossible unless you have a write protector switch.Even if it can be achieved by modifying Windows permissions of the files on the drive , other operating systems like Linux/Mac would generally ignore these settings.